# Open web page and bypass login from iPhone - iOS

Tags: ios

I want to open, from an iOS app, a web page that requires authentication in order to get to that page.

I googled a little bit and I believe I need to use `WebKit` and `Javascript injection`, but I am not sure and I have never done something like this, so every bit of information is welcomed or pointing me in the right direction.

I will give an example that I hope will make things more clear(I don't actually want to open facebook, it's just part of the example):

Is it possible to do the following scenario? And if yes, how?

Open a web page from an iOS app, for example: "https://www.facebook.com/profile" without having to go through the login page? I do have the user credentials(username and password), as the user is already logged in with those credentials in the iOS app, but the requirement is to not go through the login page, but to go straight to the profile page.

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is: no. Even if the user is already logged in and has a valid authentication token that token may only be valid from within your app and not from within the browser. And the login form may be protected by something like a captche preventing you from automatically logging someone in.

There certainly are situation where it is possible: For example if the tokens are *not* scoped to your app you can try passing them along. Or there is an actual API that you can call with the token that logs the user into the website on the website, etc. But those depend on the specific target website or wether you can control that target website and can add this functionality.